# Como instalar o rvm no Debian squeeze

Tags: ruby, linux

Estou tentando instalar o rvm mas não estou conseguindo. Na hora de fazer a verificação das dependências ele reclama do pacote libgmp-dev que não está instalado e ao tentar instalar ele não é localizado.

Pelo que andei pesquisando e parece que realmente não existe esse pacote para o squeeze ou o pacote está com outro nome...

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, não possuo o debian para efetuar testes.

No momento com o Mint instalado qualquer teste feito não seria válido.

Portanto sugiro que tente instalar uma versão compatível com a última distribuição do debian contida nesta página:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgmp-dev

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente executar os seguinte passos:

**Instale alguns pre-requisitos do Debian**

```
apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion locales-all python libxml2=2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze6
```

Agora tente instalar o RVM normalmente

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Instala o rbenv que é muito melhor que o RVM. Com o git instalado execute esse comando no terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

O ruby-build, que simplifica o modo como o Ruby é instalado.

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Adiciona o rbenv ao $PATH. Para isso execute o comando à seguir:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Adicionar o script de inicialização ao seu arquivo de inicialização do terminal. Execute o comando.

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Reinicie o seu terminal para carregar estas novas configurações, ou execute o comando `source ~/.bashrc.`

Se tudo deu certo. Agora você pode instalar o ruby. Para saber quais versões estão disponíveis, execute o comando rbenv install -l.

```
$ rbenv install -l
Available versions:
  1.8.6-p383
  1.8.6-p420
  1.8.7-p249
  1.8.7-p302
  1.8.7-p334
  ...
```

Para instalar a última versão disponível neste momento, exeute o comando `rbenv install 2.3.1.` Este processo irá demorar um pouco, já que o rbenv irá compilar o Ruby.

Quando a instalação acabar, execute o comando rbenv global 2.3.1 para definir a versão global do Ruby/

Para exibir a versão do Ruby, execute o comando ruby -v.

Opinião próprio sobre o  rbenv ser superior ao RMV e a possiblidade de instalar plugins para facilitar sua vida.Um deles é o rbenv-gem-rehash, que faz rehashing automaticamente sempre que uma gem for instalada ou removida.

"Rehashing é o processo de atualizar o $PATH com os binários das gems. O comando rbenv init faz isso para você, mas ele é apenas executado quando uma nova sessão do terminal é iniciada; assim, qualquer gem instalada após esta etapa pode não funcionar corretamente, a menos que você execute manualmente o comando rbenv rehash."

Execute o comando à seguir para instalar o plugin:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash
```

fonte: [Blog Nando Vieira](https://nandovieira.com.br/configurando-ruby-rails-mysql-postgresql-git-no-ubuntu)